# Búsqueda con LIKE que no diferencie mayúsculas, minúsculas ni acentos en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo que realizar una búsqueda en una base de datos. Utilizo la sentencia LIKE, pero el problema que encuentro es que hace distinción de tildes y de mayúsculas, por lo tanto no encuentra los resultados.

Ejemplo:

```
insert into post VALUES('¿Qué visitar cerca del Hotel Aquamarina Beach Cancún?','Cancún es uno de los destinos más visitados en México por sus playas hermosas, ya sea para disfrutar en familia, con la pareja o para disfrutar de la buena fiesta con amigos','tugfa.PNG')
```

Y esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM post where titulo like '%hotel aquamarina cancun beach%' or descripción like '%hotel aquamarina cancun beach%';
```

Y no me da ningún resultado.

¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Añade tu código para ver como lo estas haciendo para apoyarte

Comment: Ya modifiqué mi consulta

Comment: Solo como aclaración, el dato en la tabla `"Hotel Aquamarina Beach Cancún"` es distinto a la consulta `'%hotel aquamarina cancun beach%'` por el orden de las últimas dos palabras.

Comment: Colocando el acento en "Cancún" si devuelve el resultado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Especifica en tu `SELECT` un `COLLATION` que sea no-sensitivo a los acentos:

```
SELECT *
  FROM post
 WHERE titulo COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CI_AI LIKE '%Cancun%'
```

Te dejo esta [referencia de Microsoft sobre los `COLLATION` (en inglés)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250.aspx) y esta otra de [ejemplo para los acentos (en español)](http://www.compartir-tecnologias.es/consulta-sql-con-acentos-y-sin-acentos-es-posible-ayuda-208330091.html). Fuera de eso, se me hace raro que te distinga las mayúsculas de las minusculas, ya que por default es no-sensitivo. Prueba a correr la siguiente consulta para ver la configuración al respecto de tu tabla:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, collation_name
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE table_name = 'post'
```

UPDATE:

La consulta que buscas y que complementé en los comentarios es esta:

```
SELECT *
  FROM post
 WHERE titulo COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CI_AI LIKE '%hotel aquamarina cancun beach%'
       OR descripción COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CI_AI LIKE '%hotel aquamarina cancun beach%';
```

Comment: Está bien hecha mi consulta así?
SELECT * FROM post WHERE titulo COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CI_AI LIKE '%hotel aquamarina cancun beach%' or descripción like '%hotel aquamarina cancun beach%';

Comment: Faltó especificar el `COLLATE` en la segunda condición, debería quedar así: `SELECT * FROM post WHERE titulo COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CI_AI LIKE '%hotel aquamarina cancun beach%' OR descripción COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CI_AI LIKE '%hotel aquamarina cancun beach%';`.

Comment: Si, de esa forma me funciona

Comment: ¡Me alegro! Si la respuesta fue útil, no olvides marcarla como la solución a tu pregunta para que la gente que tenga el mismo problema sepa que hay una solución, del lado izquierdo encontrarás la opción para marcarla. ¡Buen día! :D

Comment: Entonces, se puede decir que el collate, permite que se ignoren los acentos, mayusculas o minusculas?

Comment: De hecho el `COLLATE` indica ambos, al final tiene `CI` de *Case Insensitive* (no-sensitivo a mayúsculas/minúsculas) y `AI` de *Accent Insensitive* (no-sensitivo a acentos é, è, ë, etc.).

Comment: Excelente, ya entendí muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Presento una solución mas sencilla, simplemente aplica la función UPPER(campo) en el WHERE y luego en el LIKE escribe el termino en mayúsculas.

```
SELECT * FROM post where UPPER(titulo) like '%HOTEL AQUAMARINA CANCUN BEACH%' or UPPER(descripción) like '%HOTEL AQUAMARINA CANCUN BEACH%';
```

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias, si también este sirve :)

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo por lo que dices que tiene un campo en una tabla con un COLLATE determinado que lo hace sensible a Mayúsculas/minúsculas y a los acentos. Obviamente en estos casos el LIKE se comporta de la misma forma, `Arriba` es distinto a `arriba` y `solución` es distinto a `solucion`. En estos casos, si no existe la alternativa de modificar el COLLATE del campo o del SELECT como bien te sugiere @Kroneaux Schneider, la única solución es mejorar el LIKE para poder resolver el problema.

Para el problema Mayúsculas/minúsculas podemos hacer algo así:

```
WHERE LOWER(campo) LIKE LOWER('%Arriba%')
```

Para el problema de los acentos, la solución es un poco más compleja pero no imposible

```
WHERE campo LIKE '%soluci[oó]n%'
```

Puede además usar varios `REPLACE` para modificar la cadena del LIKE y modificar cada vocal por su correspondiente versión acentuada.

Comment: La parte del lower no me funciona esta es mi consulta
select * from post whete lower(titulo) like lower'(%hotel aquamarina beach cancun%)'

Comment: Si estás usando SQL 2014 te recomiendo ir por la solución de @Kroneaux Schneider

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando PostgreSQL puedes usar el modulo [unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/unaccent.html) y la funcion **lower** puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE lower(unaccent(titulo)) LIKE '%hotel aquamarina cancun beach%';
```

Si estas usando MySQL deberas usar **collation** donde _CI especifica *case insensitive* y _AC *accent insensitive*

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE titulo COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%hotel aquamarina cancun beach%';
```

Comment: Estoy usando SQL SERVER 2014

Comment: @ErnestoEmmanuelYahLopez Debes usar collate guiate por el ejemplo de MySQL,